# if it is possible to send model class as a parameter in post method in alamofire and how can i ,please say

Tags: ios, swift, post

```
class DataSorce:Codable{
    var requestTimeStamp:Double
    var requestType:String
    var data : [Datas]?
    enum Codingkeys:String,CodingKey{
        case requestTimestamp = "request-timestamp"
        case requestType = "request-type"

    }
    init(requestTimeStamp:Double?,requestType:String?,data:[Datas]?) {
        self.requestTimeStamp = requestTimeStamp!
        self.requestType = requestType!
    }
}
    class Datas:Codable {
        var allowParallelLogin:Bool!
        enum Codinkeys :String,CodingKey{
        case allowParallelLogin = "allow-parallel-login"
        }
        init(allowParallelLogin:Bool?) {
            self.allowParallelLogin  = true
        }
    }

class UserInfos:Codable{
    var user:UserData?
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey{
        case user = "user-info"
    }
    init(user:UserData?){
        self.user = user
    }
}

class UserData:Codable {

    var userAppVersion: String
    var userGeoLocation: String
    var userAuthStatus: String
    var userAuthToken: String
    var userDeviceOS:String
    var userId = 0
    var userLocation: String
    var userAuthTokenExpiry = 0
    var userDeviceType:String
    var userLocationDetail:UserLocationDatails?
    var userPwd :String
    var userRole:String
    var status: Int
    var userName:String

    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey{

        case userAppVersion = "user-app-version"
        case userGeoLocation = "user-geo-location"
        case userAuthStatus = "user-auth-status"
        case userAuthToken = "user-auth-token"
        case userDeviceOS = "user-device-OS"
        case userId = "user-id"
        case userLocation = "user-location"
        case userAuthTokenExpiry = "user-auth-token-expiry"
        case userDeviceType = "user-device-type"
        case userLocationDetail = "user-location-detail"
        case userPwd = "user-pwd"
        case userRole = "user-role"
        case status = "status"
        case userName = "user-name"
    }

    init(userAppVersion: String?,userGeoLocation: String?,userAuthStatus: String?,userAuthToken: String?,userDeviceOS:String?,userLocation: String?,userDeviceType:String?,userLocationDetail:UserLocationDatails?,userId:Int?,userAuthTokenExpiry:Int?,userPwd:String?,userRole:String?,status:Int?,userName:String? ){

        self .userAppVersion = userAppVersion!
        self.userAuthStatus = userAuthStatus!
        self.userAuthToken = userAuthToken!
        self.userAuthTokenExpiry = 0
        self.userLocation = userLocation!
        self.userDeviceOS = userDeviceOS!
        self.userGeoLocation = userGeoLocation!
        self.userLocationDetail = userLocationDetail
        self.userDeviceType = userDeviceType!
        self.userId = 0
        self.userPwd = userPwd!
        self.userRole = userRole!
        self.status = 1
        self.userName = userName!
    }
        }

class UserLocationDatails:Codable {
    var street:String
    var locality:String
    var country:String
    var  longitude:String
    var city:String
    var zipcode:String
    var latitude:String
    var permission:Int
    var state:String

    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey{
        case street = "street"
        case locality = "locality"
        case country  = "country"
        case longitude = "longitude"
        case city = "city"
        case zipcode = "zipcode"
        case latitude = "latitude"
        case permission = "permission-status"
        case state = "state"
}
    init(street:String?,locality:String?,country:String?,longitude:String?,city:String?,zipcode:String?,
         latitude:String?,permission:Int?,state:String?) {
        self.street = street!
        self.locality = locality!
        self.country = country!
        self.longitude = longitude!
        self.city = city!
        self.zipcode = zipcode!
        self.latitude = latitude!
        self.permission = 0
        self.state = state!

    }
}
```

Comment: no, almofire accept dictionary as parameter

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire only accepts parameters as a dictionary.
Alamofire Documentation: public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]

You need to set your API parameters by getting values from your model.

If you haven't used pod ObjectMapper then you can use a computed property in your model or struct like:

```
class YourParamersConvertible {

    var name: String?
    var age: Int?

    init(_ name: String?, _ age: Int?) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    var parameters: [String: Any] {
        return ["name": name,
                "age": age]
    }

}

class Test: UIViewController {

    let object = YourParamersConvertible("Shehzad", 25)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let parameters = object.parameters
        print("Your Parameres: \(parameters)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible.

By using **pod 'ObjectMapper'**

Just install ObjectMapper pod.
Now while passing your post body use **.toJSON()** method.

e.g **ModelClass.toJSON()**

I hope this helps.

Thanks